# Stanley Enumerative Combinatorics Problem 33b on page 121

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am having difficulty with problem 33b in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics. The problem is attached via image. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

[Image of the Problem from Stanley](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcmcd.png)

I completed part (a) of the problem by using the fact that if $S_m$ has cardinality $r$, then you could create $S_{m+1}$ by either removing a number in $r$ ways or by adding a number in $n-r$ ways. The total number of ways to produce $S_{m+1}$ from $S_m$ would be $n$ giving the formula $n^{k}$.

For part (b) however, I noticed some patterns in the possibilities for the sequences (whether they would have an odd cardinality or even cardinality) but I am having difficulty proceeding from there.

Answer (score 1):

Two distinct solutions are given to this problem at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/71736/111804). I want to give some more details to those answers.

> **Qiaochu Yuan's answer**

Qiaochu is using a property of adjacency matrices which says that if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ and $i, j$ are vertices of $G$ then the $(i,j)$-entry of $A^k$ is the number of walks from $i$ to $j$ in $G$ of length $n$.

The number of closed walks is therefore the trace of $A^k$ which is given by

$$ \sum_{\lambda} \lambda^k $$

where the sum is over all eigenvalues of $A$.

To compute the eigenvalues of $A$ we use the fact that $A$ is the Cayley graph corresponding to the group $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^n$ with the standard generators (i.e. two elements of $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^n$ are declared adjacent if they differ by adding one of the standard basis vectors $e_i := (0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ with a single $1$ in the $i$-th position).

With a bit of Spectral graph theory, we can say that the eigenvectors are given by group characters (see Lemma 4 in [these lecture notes](http://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs359g/lecture06.pdf)).

The corresponding eigenvalue to an eigenvector $\chi$ are given by

$$ \sum_{s \in S} \chi(s) $$

where $S$ is the generating set of the Cayley graph.

The characters of $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^n$ are in one to one correspondence with $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^n$ (since it's an Abelian group). The character corresponding to the sequence $\mathbf{b}$ is

$$ \chi_{\mathbf b}(\mathbf{x}) = (-1)^{\mathbf{b}^\top \mathbf{x}} $$

So the eigenvalue of $\chi_{\mathbf b}$ where is

$$ \sum_{j = 1}^n \chi_{\mathbf b}(e_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^n (-1)^{\mathbf{b}^\top e_j} = |\mathbf{b}|(-1)^1 + (n - |\mathbf{b}|)(-1)^0 = (n - 2|\mathbf{b}|) $$

where $|\mathbf{b}| = \sum_{j = 1}^n b_j$ is the number of nonzero entries of $\mathbf{b}$. Notice that $\mathbf{b}^\top e_j = 1$ iff the $j$-th entry $b_i$ of $\mathbf{b}$ is $1$.

Thus the eigenvalues are of the form $(n - 2i)$ and we have one for each vector with $i$ ones (namely $n$ choose $i$).

> **Ira Gessel's answer**

In the theory of exponential generating series a class (or combinatorial species) is a function $\mathcal A : \text{finite sets} \to \text{finite sets}$ where the two rules are 1) if $S \ne T$ then $\mathcal{A}(S) \cap \mathcal{A}(T) = \varnothing$ and 2) $|\mathcal{A}(S)|$ depends only on the cardinality of $S$. The exponential generating function of $\mathcal{A}$ is

$$ A(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty |\mathcal{A}([n])| \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$

Given two classes $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ we define their product class $\mathcal A * \mathcal B$ by

$$ (\mathcal A * \mathcal B)(X) = \bigcup_{S \subseteq X} \mathcal A(S) \times \mathcal B(X \setminus S). $$

Notice that $S, X \setminus S$ is a partition of $X$ into two sets. Also note that if $|X| = n$ then

$$ |(\mathcal A * \mathcal B)(X)| = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} |\mathcal A([k])| \cdot |\mathcal B([n - k])|. $$

It follows that the generating series for $\mathcal {A} * \mathcal{B}$ is $A(x)B(x)$ where $A, B$ are the generating series for $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ respectively.

In general, the product of $k$ classes corresponds to partitioning a set into $k$ pieces. This is what we are doing when we take a word of length $k$ and break it into even length words of the form $i -i\; i - i \cdots i - i$. The class of words of the form $i -i\; i - i \cdots i - i$ has the generating series

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \cosh x $$

So the class of shuffles (which is a $n$-fold product) has the generating series $ (\cosh x)^n $.

We can lastly extract the answer by taking the $x^k/k!$-th coefficient of $(\cosh x)^n$. This can be done as follows

\begin{align*}
   \left[ \frac{x^k}{k!} \right](\cosh x)^n &= \left[ \frac{x^k}{k!} \right]\left( \frac{\exp(x) + \exp(-x)}{2} \right)^n \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} \left[ \frac{x^k}{k!} \right] \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} \exp((n - i)x)\exp(-ix) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} \left[ \frac{x^k}{k!} \right]\exp((n - 2i)x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} (n - 2i)^k. \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Very interesting. So essentially, my understanding is that from the definition of the sequence of sets $S_0, S_1, ..., S_k$ and the requirement that $S_k = \emptyset$ if an element of $[n]$ is added to a set (operation $+i$) it must also be removed (operation $-i$) which would allow for the generating function of $cosh \space x$ to be applied for the solution. Is this essentially correct?

Comment: @HarryXi Yes, that's right.